# Negative Lookahead in regex in .ctags file

Tags: regex, ctags

I added the rule like this : `--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*((?!(if|for|switch|while)).)*[ \t]*\(.*\)[ \t]*{/\1/M,Method,Methods/` in the `.ctags` file, but it cannot work.

Does `.ctags` file support to use `Negative Lookahead` syntax in the Regular Expression, and how can I fix my rule?

Comment: Apparently not: https://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/mailman/message/1877046/

Comment: You probably already know this, but lookaheads can be replaced with non-capturing groups. The only downside of that is that you cannot use the `Full match` to retrieve results.

Comment: You can replace them in most cases. However, the non-capturing groups consume the characters whereas lookaheads do not (so you will change the position of your capturing with non-capturing groups)

Answer (score 0):

The latest Universal ctags (https://ctags.io) [introduced](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/commit/6a8d5b709af994ff278390eed2a62d718f05a409) pcre2 as an optional regular expression engine. So you can use the Negative Lookahead in an expression if you use it.

Use `--list-features` option for verifying your ctags is linked to pcre2:

```
$  ~/bin/ctags --list-features | grep pcre2
pcre2             has pcre2 regex engine
```

Add `{pcre2}` at the end of `--regex-javascript` option like:

```
--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*((?!(if|for|switch|while))[^ \t]*)[ \t]*\(.*\)[ \t]*{/\1/Q,Method,Methods/{pcre2}
```

I used `Q` instead of `M` because `M` is already reserved by the Javascript parser of Universal Ctags.

```
$ cat /tmp/input.js 
f0 () {}
while () {}
f1 () {}
if () {}
f2 () {}
switch () {}
f3 () {}
while () {}
f4 () {}

$ ~/bin/ctags -o - --kinds-javascript=M '--regex-javascript=/^[ \t]*((?!(if|for|switch|while))[^ \t]*)[ \t]*\(.*\)[ \t]*{/\1/Q,Method,Methods/{pcre2}' /tmp/input.js 
f0  /tmp/input.js   /^f0 () {}$/;"  Q
f1  /tmp/input.js   /^f1 () {}$/;"  Q
f2  /tmp/input.js   /^f2 () {}$/;"  Q
f3  /tmp/input.js   /^f3 () {}$/;"  Q
f4  /tmp/input.js   /^f4 () {}$/;"  Q
```